# Getting BIM Surfer Working?

Tags: 3d, ifc

I’ve downloaded and installed the BIMserver “.jar” file and then downloaded BIM Surfer … I can see using console log in my browser that login was successful when I point BIM Surfer at my BIMserver … on 8082 with username and password … but then it hangs as there are no projects in my BIMserver …

The result is though I have some IFC files to upload into the BIMserver I have no GUI tool to help me:

a) create a project
b) upload the IFC content 
c) “Most Importantly” view those files through a web browser

Any help you could provide me greatly appreciated .. there's little or nothing by way of tutorials on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

You are having compatibility issue with the versions of BIMserver and BIMsurfer. Please have a look at the BIMsurfer Github Page issues:
https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMsurfer/issues/94
Let me know if you are able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wordpress, you can also try this: https://github.com/TurnereManager/3D-Model-Viewer

Instead of IFC you need to use the vA3C exporters which are in JSON: http://va3c.github.io/